# ContextualVersionConflict : Error while importing streamlit in Google Colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, streamlit

I am getting this error even after doing reset runtime . That process didn't work for me . Suggest another way.

```
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f70969ba6d2> in <module>()
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import cv2
----> 4 import streamlit as st
      5 from tensorflow import keras
      6 from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    775                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    776                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 777                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    778 
    779             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (ipykernel 4.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('ipykernel>=5.1.2; python_version >= "3.4"'), {'pydeck'})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is stating that `ipykernel` version did not match with version required by streamlit.

Use this

```py
!pip install ipykernel>=5.1.2
!pip install pydeck
```

After using the above code, click on **Runtime** and click **Restart Runtime**.

[image]

Comment: have you installed the above mentioned libraries and restart the runtime?

Comment: yes I installed the libraries and restart the runtime but still got the same error.

Comment: @AnnadataAlekhya can you give the access of colab to `pdahal2871@gmail.com`?

Comment: I shared the link to you.

Comment: @AnnadataAlekhya No there is not any invitation in my gmail account